# How to apply a function for multiple columns pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, apply

I need to calculate distances between 2 postcodes in pandas dataframe.

I am using pgeocode library to calculate distances between 2 UK Postcodes

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HGzob.png)

`dist = samp.apply(lambda x:dist.query_postal_code(x['a'],x['b']), axis=1)` -

Its not working (getting DataFrame constructor not properly called!) error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's all in your preparation

- get geo data from webservice
- prepare it as tuples and generate your combinations
- calc distance

```
import geopy.distance, requests
import pandas as pd

# a few post codes..
df = pd.DataFrame({'Name': ['BROAD STREET DENTAL SURGERY',
  'KINGTON SURGERY',
  'ALTON STREET SURGERY'],
 'PostCode': ['HR4 9AR', 'HR5 3EA', 'HR9 5AB']})


# get geo data for postcodes
dfgeo = (pd.json_normalize(requests.post("http://api.postcodes.io/postcodes", 
               json={"postcodes":df.PostCode.unique().tolist()}).json()["result"])
         # make long / lat a tuple
         .assign(geo=lambda d: d.loc[:,["result.longitude","result.latitude"]].apply(lambda r: tuple(r), axis=1))
         .loc[:,["result.postcode","geo"]]
         .rename(columns={"result.postcode":"PostCode"})
        )

# merge geo data with original postcode data
df = df.merge(dfgeo, on="PostCode")

# generate all combinations, remove to self...
dfd = (df.assign(foo=1).merge(df.assign(foo=1), on="foo", suffixes=("_addr1","_addr2"))
 .drop(columns=["foo"]).loc[lambda d: d.PostCode_addr1!=d.PostCode_addr2]
 # all prep done,  let's calc distance
 .assign(miles=lambda d: d.apply(lambda r: geopy.distance.distance(r["geo_addr1"], r["geo_addr2"]).miles, axis=1))
)
```

|  | Name_addr1 | PostCode_addr1 | geo_addr1 | Name_addr2 | PostCode_addr2 | geo_addr2 | miles |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | BROAD STREET DENTAL SURGERY | HR4 9AR | (-2.717611, 52.055269) | KINGTON SURGERY | HR5 3EA | (-3.022556, 52.199361) | 23.1971 |
| 2 | BROAD STREET DENTAL SURGERY | HR4 9AR | (-2.717611, 52.055269) | ALTON STREET SURGERY | HR9 5AB | (-2.582971, 51.911934) | 13.5525 |
| 3 | KINGTON SURGERY | HR5 3EA | (-3.022556, 52.199361) | BROAD STREET DENTAL SURGERY | HR4 9AR | (-2.717611, 52.055269) | 23.1971 |
| 5 | KINGTON SURGERY | HR5 3EA | (-3.022556, 52.199361) | ALTON STREET SURGERY | HR9 5AB | (-2.582971, 51.911934) | 36.1468 |
| 6 | ALTON STREET SURGERY | HR9 5AB | (-2.582971, 51.911934) | BROAD STREET DENTAL SURGERY | HR4 9AR | (-2.717611, 52.055269) | 13.5525 |
| 7 | ALTON STREET SURGERY | HR9 5AB | (-2.582971, 51.911934) | KINGTON SURGERY | HR5 3EA | (-3.022556, 52.199361) | 36.1468 |

Comment: Perfect, Exactly as I need. Thanks Rob

Answer (score 0):

You need to refer to the `column-names` in your database to access the underyling values.

Change it to

```py
dist = samp.apply(lambda x:dist.query_postal_code(x['Postcode.x'],x['Postcode.y']), axis=1)
```